# loadCustomPropertiesAsync method times out on Outlook for Android

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in that attempts to fetch a custom property that is stored with the mail item using the loadCustomPropertiesAsync [1]:

```js
  Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(function(asyncResult){
    var customProps = asyncResult.value;
    console.log(customProps.get("some.prop"));
})
```

The above snippet of code seems to time out when I access the add-in from Outlook for Android (v3.0.40) app, but works fine on iOS, Firefox and Chrome (Tested on both Windows 10 and Mac ).

Is this a bug?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.3/office.context.mailbox.item

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.